# Any command to view the file system internal fragmentation size under a directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage, ext3

If the block size of a file system is 4KB, then for a 1KB file, 3KB space(which is internal fragmentation) is wasted. So, under a directory, is there any command to summarize how much disk space is wasted due to internal fragmentation?

Comment: Maybe a more useful metric (and easier to obtain and define) would be to compare the disk usage (which accounts for that fragmentation but also compression, sparseness, block sharing...) with the some of the file sizes.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: @jippie I'm using ext3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except if you have sparse files, it sounds like you're looking for `du -s «dir»` vs. `du -s --apparent-size «dir»`.

Or, in `stat` output, the difference between size and blocks × block size:

```
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ echo -n 1 > foo 
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ stat -c '%s    %b × %B' foo 
1    8 × 512
```

And with `du` (which defaults to kilobytes, add `-B 1` if you want bytes):

```
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ du foo 
4       foo
anthony@Zia:/tmp$ du --apparent-size foo 
1       foo
```

`du` will of course count entire directory trees, not just individual files.